# 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter' while using JSQMessagesCollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using [JSQMessagesViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) to add chat functionality to my app. Inside a UIViewController, I initialised a JSQMessagesCollectionView thus:

```
JSQMessagesCollectionView *jsq = [[JSQMessagesCollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:jsq];
```

This however, is giving me this error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
```

How would I include the view inside my view controller? A brief explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use the designated initializer.  If you don't know what that means, google for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **JSQMessagesCollectionView**, there is no public method to initialize the class from your class. But there is one private init method available i.e. `- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame collectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout`.

This is the reason you are getting **nil**.

As per documentation, better to use **JSQMessagesViewController**.

Hope the solution helps.